# Understand Perl snippet with @ and %

Tags: perl

I have following Perl code. I read @ is for array and % hash, so I'm a bit confused re what code does, especially the `foreach $pron (keys %LEX)` statement. What is the purpose of each element in this line & is LEX an array or hash?

```
while ( $line = <STDIN> ) {
     chomp $line;
     ($key, $val) = split " ", $line, 2;
     $val = join(" ", split(" ", $val));
     push @{$LEX{$val}}, $key;
   }

   open(MAP, "| sort -u > $ARGV[1]") or die "Cannot open $ARGV[1]\n";
   foreach $val (keys %LEX) {
     $head = $LEX{$val}->[0];
     foreach $alt (@{$LEX{$val}}) {
       print MAP "$alt,$head\n";
     }
   }
```

Comment: Not sure what you want to understand, and not going to really post an answer as the question is off topic here and it is of no use to copy/paste documentation here, but in short. It assigns values to keys, pushes key/value pairs to hash `%LEX` by doing `push @{$LEX{$val}}, $key;` Then `foreach $val (keys %LEX)` you use the key/value pairs again. To understand it better see [perldoc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html)

Comment: You are wrong. `push @{$LEX{$val}}, $key` pushes key/value pairs to a hash holding an array. This is the tricky point hinted to in the question name. otherwise it would be something like $LEX{$val}=$key.

Comment: I am not wrong, I gave a very short comment to your unclear question.

Comment: @grunt: Gerhard is describing the entire code sample correctly. Please be more polite.

Answer (score 2):

Inside a `foreach` loop a local scalar variable is assigned each value of the list of values in the round brackets one after another:

```
for my $foo (1 .. 3) {
    say "-> $foo";
}
```

Output:

```
-> 1
-> 2
-> 3
```

Here `keys %LEX` returns the *list* of keys of the Hash `%LEX`, so here `$val` contains a key of `%LEX` each time the loop is executed. In this case the variable is poorly named, I would consider `$key` instead.

The next line, `$head = $LEX{$val}->[0];` implies, that the *values* of the hash `%LEX` are *array references*. `$LEX{$val}` is a single scalar value and the arrow operator dereferences the array. Then its first element is used.

See [perlref](http://p3rl.org/perlref) and [perldata](http://p3rl.org/perldata) for details using references and nested data structures.